# Gnuplotting the sorted merge of two CSV files

Tags: csv, unix, awk, merge, gnuplot

I am trying to merge and sort two CSV files skipping the first 8 rows.

I try to sort one of the files by the 36th column I use:

```
awk '(NR>8 ){print; }' Hight_5x5.csv | sort -nk36
```

and to merge the two files:

```
cat Hight_5x5.csv <(tail +8 Hight_5x5_b.csv)
```

The `sort` command it does not work.

I would like two use both actions in a command and send the result to the `plot` command of gnuplot. I have tried this line:

```
awk '(NR>8 ){print; }' (cat Hight_5x5.csv <(tail +8 Hight_5x5_b.csv)) | sort -nk36
```

and it does merge the two files but it does not sort by column 36, thus I assume in gnuplot `plot` command will not work too.

```
plot "<awk '(NR>8 ){print; }' (cat Hight_5x5.csv <(tail +8 Hight_5x5_b.csv)) | sort -nk36"
```

The problem is the format of the two files. The data have `","` separations. For example, `...,"0.041","3.5","40","false","1000","1.3","20","5","5","-20","2","100000000","0.8",...`.

This [link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ool5ab361ku19zc/AAB-p56TqHDAbAKGIiDNNfqNa?dl=0) has the two CSV files.

Regards

Comment: Your file has 7 lines of header surely?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'FNR>8' file1 file2 | sort -k36n
```

should do, I guess you should be able to pipe to `gnuplot` as well.

Don't understand your comment, `sort` will sort.  Perhaps you don't have 36 fields or your separator is not white space, which you have to specify.

Here is an example with dummy data with comma separated fields

```
$ awk 'FNR>3' <(seq 20 | paste - - -d,) <(seq 10 | shuf | paste - - -d,) | sort -t, -k2n
5,1
2,7
7,8
9,10
11,12
13,14
15,16
17,18
19,20
```

Comment: @karafka I apologize, but I have taken a better look at the result of the answer, and it merges the two files, but it does not sort the result after the merge.

Comment: You are right, it is probably the format of the data. This is the format of my data ..."0.0011","7549563","13798.23111419471","4","6","2","108","1001","46","2581","367","8","20000","0.8",.... I have more than 36 columns.

Comment: I think the "," separation format is the problem. I have added above a link with my two files. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @karakfa I have placed a new question related because this answer does not work. Regards.